# How to translate IDL's SPLINE function to Python [particularly for the case we have 3 data points]

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, idl-programming-language

The [SPLINE function in IDL](https://lancesimms.com/programs/IDL/idl_functions/spline.pro) allows for cubic interpolation on data (with at at least 3 data points). While the Scipy library in Python can perfomr similar computations with the [UnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline) and the [splrep](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Scipy/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) functions, these break if the interpolations are set to cubic ones and we have just 3 data points ([something that doesn't happen with SPLINE](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/SPLINE.html)).

This is a simple example of what SPLINE does in IDL:

```
> x = [2., 3., 4.]
> y = (x-3)^2
> t = FINDGEN(20)/10.+2
> z = SPLINE(x, y, t)
> print, z

1.00000     0.810662     0.642087     0.493590     0.364684     0.255081     0.164684    0.0935898    0.0420876    0.0106618      0.00000    0.0106618    0.0420876    0.0935898     0.164684     0.255081     0.364684     0.493590      0.642087     0.810662
```

But if I try to do this in Python with
from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev

```
x = np.array([2., 3., 4.])
y = (x-3)**2
t = np.arange(20)/10.+2
z = splev(t, splrep(x, y, k = 3))
```

or with
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

```
x = np.array([2., 3., 4.])
y = (x-3)**2
t = np.arange(20)/10.+2
z = UnivariateSpline(x, y, k = 3)(t)
```

I always get this error message:

```py
TypeError: m > k must hold
```

Which I understand since there can't be a unique k-degree polynomial solution when we have to fit m data points if m ≤ k. But then it begs the question... How does SPLINE in IDL performs this calculation? And how can I reporduce it in Python?

I can try by lowering the polynomical to k = 2 (a quadratic interpolation), like so

```py
z = splev(t, splrep(x, y, k = 2))
```

or

```py
z = UnivariateSpline(x, y, k = 2)(t)
```

And I will get in both cases:

```py
> print(z)
[1. 0.81 0.64 0.49 0.36 0.25 0.16 0.09 0.04 0.01 0. 0.01 0.04 0.09 0.16 0.25 0.36 0.49 0.64 0.81]
```

Which is certainly similar to the output in IDL unless we ignore everything below the second decimal place.

How can I perform the same calculations as SPLINE in Python, even in the case that k = m like SPLINE does?

Comment: From the documentation: This routine is written in the IDL language. Its source code can be found in the file spline.pro in the lib subdirectory of the IDL distribution.

Comment: @jitter The first link I added is precisely that code. But I want to know how to make it in python if there's a shorter way than reproducing the entire code.

Comment: Sorry, not sure about that. But it does not look hard to translate those few lines to python. Or is there anything you don't understand in the IDL code?

Comment: @jitter Yeah the code might not be difficult but I'm asking because I need to know. I don't want to translate and test a 170 line code for a simple functionality and lose an entire day of work doing so when there's probably a one-line solution somewhere in scipy or numpy that someone might know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this remained unanswered, I've translated the 170 lines of code of [SPLINE.pro](https://lancesimms.com/programs/IDL/idl_functions/spline.pro) to Python3, as so:

```
import numpy as np

def spline(X, Y, T, sigma = 1.0):
    n = min(len(X), len(Y))
    if n <= 2:
        print('X and Y must be arrays of 3 or more elements.')
    if sigma != 1.0:
        sigma = min(sigma, 0.001)
    yp = np.zeros(2*n)
    delx1 = X[1]-X[0]
    dx1 = (Y[1]-Y[0])/delx1
    nm1 = n-1
    nmp = n+1
    delx2 = X[2]-X[1]
    delx12 = X[2]-X[0]
    c1 = -(delx12+delx1)/(delx12*delx1)
    c2 = delx12/(delx1*delx2)
    c3 = -delx1/(delx12*delx2)
    slpp1 = c1*Y[0]+c2*Y[1]+c3*Y[2]
    deln = X[nm1]-X[nm1-1]
    delnm1 = X[nm1-1]-x[nm1-2]
    delnn = X[nm1]-X[nm1-2]
    c1 = (delnn+deln)/(delnn*deln)
    c2 = -delnn/(deln*delnm1)
    c3 = deln/(delnn*delnm1)
    slppn = c3*Y[nm1-2]+c2*Y[nm1-1]+c1*Y[nm1]
    sigmap = sigma*nm1/(X[nm1]-X[0])
    dels = sigmap*delx1
    exps = np.exp(dels)
    sinhs = 0.5*(exps-1/exps)
    sinhin = 1/(delx1*sinhs)
    diag1 = sinhin*(dels*0.5*(exps+1/exps)-sinhs)
    diagin = 1/diag1
    yp[0] = diagin*(dx1-slpp1)
    spdiag = sinhin*(sinhs-dels)
    yp[n] = diagin*spdiag
    delx2 = X[1:]-X[:-1]
    dx2 = (Y[1:]-Y[:-1])/delx2
    dels = sigmap*delx2
    exps = np.exp(dels)
    sinhs = 0.5*(exps-1/exps)
    sinhin = 1/(delx2*sinhs)
    diag2 = sinhin*(dels*(0.5*(exps+1/exps))-sinhs)
    diag2 = np.concatenate([np.array([0]), diag2[:-1]+diag2[1:]])
    dx2nm1 = dx2[nm1-1]
    dx2 = np.concatenate([np.array([0]), dx2[1:]-dx2[:-1]])
    spdiag = sinhin*(sinhs-dels)
    for i in range(1, nm1):
        diagin = 1/(diag2[i]-spdiag[i-1]*yp[i+n-1])
        yp[i] = diagin*(dx2[i]-spdiag[i-1]*yp[i-1])
        yp[i+n] = diagin*spdiag[i]
    diagin = 1/(diag1-spdiag[nm1-1]*yp[n+nm1-1])
    yp[nm1] = diagin*(slppn-dx2nm1-spdiag[nm1-1]*yp[nm1-1])
    for i in range(n-2, -1, -1):
        yp[i] = yp[i]-yp[i+n]*yp[i+1]
    m = len(T)
    subs = np.repeat(nm1, m)
    s = X[nm1]-X[0]
    sigmap = sigma*nm1/s
    j = 0
    for i in range(1, nm1+1):
        while T[j] < X[i]:
            subs[j] = i
            j += 1
            if j == m:
                break
        if j == m:
            break
    subs1 = subs-1
    del1 = T-X[subs1]
    del2 = X[subs]-T
    dels = X[subs]-X[subs1]
    exps1 = np.exp(sigmap*del1)
    sinhd1 = 0.5*(exps1-1/exps1)
    exps = np.exp(sigmap*del2)
    sinhd2 = 0.5*(exps-1/exps)
    exps = exps1*exps
    sinhs = 0.5*(exps-1/exps)
    spl = (yp[subs]*sinhd1+yp[subs1]*sinhd2)/sinhs+((Y[subs]-yp[subs])*del1+(Y[subs1]-yp[subs1])*del2)/dels
    if m == 1:
        return spl[0]
    else:
        return spl
```

Now everything works as expected and the result are the exact same as in IDL.

```
x = np.array([2., 3., 4.])
y = (x-3)**2
t = np.arange(20)/10.+2
z = spline(x, y, t)

> print(z)
[1.         0.81066204 0.64208752 0.49359014 0.36468451 0.25508134
 0.16468451 0.09359014 0.04208752 0.01066204 0.         0.01066204
 0.04208752 0.09359014 0.16468451 0.25508134 0.36468451 0.49359014
 0.64208752 0.81066204]
```